# How to make Criteria on SELECT CASE in Symfony 1.4 Propel

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, criteria, propel

I am looking a way to make Criteria based on this SQL in Symfony 1.4:

```
SELECT item.position, 
CASE 
    WHEN item.position = 1 THEN item.position + 1
    WHEN item.position = 2 THEN item.position - 1
    ELSE item.position
END AS new_position
FROM item ORDER BY new_position ASC
```

I was trying to use example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860871/propel-pseudo-column-sorting),
but it doesn't help

It is important to make `$criteria`, because it is later passed to plugin that render list of items and sort items by `$criteria`.

`WHEN` condition is only example, I will use more complicated conditions.

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/propel-users/MF9H_V7Mijc) ?

Comment: @j0k
I've tried to use this code but in best case I have "Notice: Undefined offset".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a php switch in your Query.php class to build the criteria ( since your question shows simplified example, the switch needs for your criteria may be much more complex):

```
//in YourModelQuery.php
public function addMyItemPositionCriteria($itemPosition) {
    //TODO: validate $itemPosition values as needed
    switch ($itemPosition) {
        case 1:
            return $this->add([$criteria see http://api.propelorm.org/1.6.8/ browse propel.runtime.query Criteria and ModelCriteria classes ]);
            break;
        case 2:
            return $this->add([$criteria here]);
            break;
        }
}
```

Or you can similarly build a $criteria object in your ModelPeer.php class (or action class without the function call):

```
// in MyObjectPeerClass.php
public static function addMyItemPositionCriteria($itemPosition) {
    //TODO: validate $itemPosition values as needed
    $criteria = new Criteria;
    switch ($itemPosition) {
        case 1:
            return $criteria->add([$criteria see http://api.propelorm.org/1.6.8/ browse propel.runtime.query Criteria and ModelCriteria classes ]);
            break;
        case 2:
            return $criteria->add([$criteria here]);
            break;
        }
}
```

You can then put this criteria to use:

```
//depending on context
// in ModelQuery.php call 
    $this->addMyItemPostion($itemPosition);
// call to model query
    ModelQuery::create()->addMyItemPosition($itemPosition)->find();
//in action or somewhere else (adding to previously defined $criteria)
    $new_criteria = MyObjectPeerClass::addMyItemPosition($itemPosition);
    $criteria->add($new_criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the statement "withColumn", then custom your query

->withColumn("CASE WHEN CLIENTE_ID = {$cliente->getId()} THEN 'Pontos Pessoais' ELSE 'Pontos de Equipe' END", 'descricao')